# When did Stack Exchange debut?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stackexchange.com, company, stack-exchange-history

https://stackoverflow.com/company says y'all started in 2008.

https://stackexchange.com/about says y'all started in 2010.

Which is correct?

Comment: Both? StackOverflow and StackExchange didn't start at the same time. Like Apple didn't start with the release of the first iPhone.

Comment: Sounds reasonable as my SO account is from 2008 and I remember there was no other site at that time ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both are correct. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) are two different **websites**.

*[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)* was launched in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. Later, in 2009, Joel's company [Glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch_(New_York_company)) (then known as Fog Creek Software) released a beta for Stack Exchange. It wasn't too successful...

In 2010, Stack Overflow (now a brand of a company) launched Stack Exchange (website) proper, which began to include other websites launched through [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/about), such as [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

The distinction in these *about* pages is specific to the parent site.

Comment: [Glitch / Fog Creek Software was acquired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch_(New_York_company)) by [Fastly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastly) in 2022. *"Glitch's staff had declined since 2020 from 50 to 14 employees"*